# Combining Data.Dynamic and type classes

Tags: haskell, dynamic, typeclass

Given a variable of type `Dynamic`, it it possible to take advantage of the type classes of the internal variable without conditioning on the exact type?  For example, let's say I want to write a function `prettyShow`.  If the internal type is an instance of `Show`, then we should use that instance; otherwise, we should use the instance of the `Dynamic` class.  In code, this might look like:

```
prettyShow :: Dynamic -> String
prettyShow x = case fromDynamic x :: (forall a. Show a => Maybe a) of
    Nothing -> show x
    Just y -> show y
```

Edit: Since it appears this can't be done directly, what are some good workaround that can be done?

Comment: In short, no.  I would love for this information to be available, but class information is lost and only a typerep remains after compilation.

Comment: But surely there could be a big table in memory somewhere that associates each typerep with its class dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the implementation of `Dynamic` in the [open-typerep](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/open-typerep) library (if you accept using generic programming and lots of GHC extensions).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.TypeRep

type Types = BoolType :+: IntType :+: ListType

x, y :: Dynamic Types
x = toDyn [False,True]
y = toDyn [1, 2 :: Int]

test1 = show x
test2 = show y
```

The definition of `show` is simple, and you can use the library to define other functions over dynamic values.

In the above example I used a closed type universe `Type`. But using Data Types à la Carte tricks you can also define functions for open universes. For example, `show` itself is open.

**Performance**

A [simple benchmark](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/open-typerep/blob/master/benchmarks/Dynamic.hs) shows that this `Dynamic` is 2-3 times slower than `Data.Dynamic` in `base` for the small type universe used above. Increasing the universe to 30 type constructors makes it a bit more than 10 times slower.

**Auto deriving for new types**

`open-typerep` supports making universes from a small number of predefined representation types. It should in principle be possible to use TemplateHaskell to auto-derive representations for new types, but it will be tricky to generate the right instances for `Witness` and `PWitness` as these depend on what other instances are available. (`Witness` is used e.g. by the `Show` instance for `Dynamic`.)

Comment: What's the performance difference between this and Data.Dynamic?  Can your `Typeable` class be automatically derived for types that I don't have control over?